# R: extract matrix from array, using a matrix of indices

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I´m coding in R and I have a 3 dimensional array that contains data (ab in the example). Then I have a matrix that contains indices of the 3rd array dimension (idx). This matrix has the same number of rows and columns of the array. I want to use the indices contained in idx to extract data from the array, to get a matrix with same dimension of idx. Please see the example below:

```
a <- c(1:9)
b <- rev(a)

#array of data
ab <- array(c(a,b), dim = c(3,3,2))
ab
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9    6    3
[2,]    8    5    2
[3,]    7    4    1

#matrix of indices
idx <- matrix(sample(1:2,9,replace=TRUE), nrow = 3)
idx
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

#now I want to get the following matrix:
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9    6    3
[2,]    8    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

#these two don´t do the job
ab[idx]
ab[ , ,idx]
```

Does anybody know how can I get that?

Many thanks!

Sara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need an index for row/column and the third dimension (from 'idx') to extract the elements.  We do this by `cbind`ing the row index, column index with the 'idx'.

```
i1 <- dim(ab)[1]
j1 <- dim(ab)[2]
matrix(ab[cbind(rep(seq_len(i1),  j1),rep(seq_len(j1), each = i1), c(idx))], ncol=3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    9    6    3
#[2,]    8    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit complicated, but it works at least: 
First of all my idx:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    1
[2,]    1    2    1
[3,]    2    2    2
```

First I made it both to a vector:

```
idVec <- as.vector(idx)
d3mat <- apply(ab,3,as.vector)
```

Then I constructed a vector, to run over each element:

```
len <- length(idVec)
len <- 1:len
```

Then I apllied a function to each element of the vector len:

```
resultvec <- sapply(len, function(x, vec, mat){return(mat[x,vec[x]])}, mat=d3mat, vec=idVec)
```

And then transform the result back to a matrix:

```
    matrix(resultVec,3,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9    6    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    7    4    1
```