# extract array from array

Tags: arrays, r

I wish to extract an `array` from an `array`.  Here is a small example `array`, `my.array2`:

```
x = cbind(1:5, 6:10, 12:16)
y = cbind(c(11,3,12,14,15), c(16,8,15,17,20), 6:10)
z = cbind(c(21,21,22,3,25), c(26,28,25,8,20), 36:40)

my.array  <- array(c(x, y), dim = c(5, 3, 2))
my.array2 <- array(c(my.array, z), dim = c(5, 3, 3))
my.array2
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   12
[2,]    2    7   13
[3,]    3    8   14
[4,]    4    9   15
[5,]    5   10   16

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   16    6
[2,]    3    8    7
[3,]   12   15    8
[4,]   14   17    9
[5,]   15   20   10

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   21   26   36
[2,]   21   28   37
[3,]   22   25   38
[4,]    3    8   39
[5,]   25   20   40
```

I wish to extract the rows in which the first column is `3` and the second column is `8` resulting in this `array`:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    8   14

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    8    7

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    8   39
```

and then this `data.frame`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    8   14
[2,]    3    8    7
[3,]    3    8   39
```

Here are a couple of attempts that failed:

```
my.array2[my.array2[,1,] == 3 & my.array2[,2,] == 8,,]

my.array2[my.array2[,1,] == 3 & my.array2[,2,] == 8,my.array2[,1,] == 3 & my.array2[,2,] == 8,my.array2[,1,] == 3 & my.array2[,2,] == 8]
```

I would prefer a solution in base `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [R: extract matrix from array, using a matrix of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344473/r-extract-matrix-from-array-using-a-matrix-of-indices) to get elements from the array, we can do the following:

```
df = apply(my.array2, 2, as.vector)
# Select rows which meet criteria
df = data.frame(df[df[,1] == 3 & df[,2] == 8, ])
> df
  X1 X2 X3
1  3  8 14
2  3  8  7
3  3  8 39
```

Answer (score 2):

This will first construct a matrix with NULLs in the positions where those column conditions (hence the c(1,3) index) are not met and the desired "rows" where they are met, and then it will `rbind` them:

```
Reduce( rbind, apply(my.array2, c(1,3), function(x)if(x[1]==3&x[2]==8){x}) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    8   14
[2,]    3    8    7
[3,]    3    8   39
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This solution does not  use `apply` or functions that apply another function iteratively.

Permute the indices of the array using `aperm` so that the 2nd dimension is last, reform that into a matrix with `dim(my.array2)[2]` columns, convert that to a data frame and subset it down to the required rows.  A single statement to do that is:

```
subset(as.data.frame(matrix(aperm(my.array2, c(1, 3, 2)),, dim(my.array2)[2])), 
   V1 == 3 & V2 == 8)
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2 V3
3   3  8 14
7   3  8  7
14  3  8 39
```

**2)** We could shorten this slightly by replacing `dim(my.array2)[2]` with `3` if hard coding that dimension size is not a problem.

**3)** We could also express this using a pipeline like this:

```
library(dplyr)

my.array2 %>%
  aperm(c(1, 3, 2)) %>%
  matrix(ncol = dim(.)[3]) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  filter(V1 == 3 & V2 == 8)
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1  3  8 14
## 2  3  8  7
## 3  3  8 39
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  All four are worthy of the check mark.  I am wondering whether you might consider checking which is the fastest.  Also, curiously, all four seem to go directly to the data.frame without creating an intermediate array.  I do not know whether there is any value in creating the intermediate array.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best answer but one way is

```
data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y) my.array2[y, , x], 1:dim(my.array2)[3], 
          data.frame(my.array2[, 1,] == 3 & my.array2[, 2,] == 8))))

#  X1 X2 X3
#1  3  8 14
#2  3  8  7
#3  3  8 39
```

We first check which rows have 3 in first column and 8 in second

```
my.array2[, 1,] == 3 & my.array2[, 2,] == 8

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now we should have got the answer from here itself as this shows we want to select 3rd row from 1st matrix, 2nd row from 2nd matrix and 4th row from 3rd matrix but to select those individual rows from each matrix we need to loop over them using `mapply` and select individual rows from each matrix and then convert it to dataframe.