# Efficient subsetting of each column of a matrix with a column of indices of another matrix

Tags: r, vectorization, coding-efficiency

I am currently facing this problem while working on R.

I have a big matrix, say A, of size (M x K) and a smaller matrix, say B, of size (N x K), with of course N < M. So B has the same number of columns as A, but less rows.

A possible example can be:

```
A <- replicate(K, rnorm(M))
B <- replicate(K, sample(M, N))
```

My goal is to **subset each column of A with the correspondent column of B in an efficent way**, since the dimension of the matrices is huge.

A possible numerical example is:

```
A <- [1 2 3     B <- [1 1 3   --->   [1 2 9
      4 5 6           3 2 2]          7 5 6]
      7 8 9]
```

This means I am looking for something better than parsing column-by-column using a simple for loop:

```
 for(i in 1:K)
 { 
   A[B[,i],i] 
 }
```

Thank you for helping me to solve this apparently trivial, but for me challenging problem.

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344473/r-extract-matrix-from-array-using-a-matrix-of-indices) and `?'['`:

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as
> many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector
> with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

For your example, it would be:

```
A <- matrix(1:9, 3, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2), 2, byrow = TRUE)
C <- matrix(A[cbind(c(B), rep(1:ncol(B), each = nrow(B)))], nrow(B))
```

UPDATE: For efficiency, Mossa is right. There's not going to be much of a difference in performance in this case between using a matrix of indices and looping. Almost all of your time is in generating `A`. Generating `B` even takes longer than generating `C`:

```
M <- K <- 1e4; N <- 1e3

> system.time(A <- replicate(K, rnorm(M)))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.110   0.922   8.030 
> system.time(B <- replicate(K, sample(M, N)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.727   0.033   0.760 
> system.time(C <- matrix(A[cbind(c(B), rep(1:ncol(B), each = nrow(B)))], nrow(B)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.474   0.186   0.659
```

You can speed up the generation of `A` slightly by sampling all in one go, but you don't have much room for improvement in any of the `A`, `B`, `C` operations:

```
> system.time(A <- matrix(rnorm(M*K), M))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.82    0.74    7.56
```

Comment: On my machine, this solution has iter/sec 25k, while the loop version has 26k. So this is faster, but not by that much. This is when I use N = 100, M = 150, K = 13.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you've arrived at a pretty reasonable method:

```r
    C <- matrix(NA, nrow = N, ncol = K)
    for (i in seq_len(K))
    {
      C[, i] <- A[B[, i], i]
    }
    C
```